# Movement Paths & Spatial-Temporal Queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial, temporal

Hey, so I'm trying to figure out the best way of storing movement paths and then afterwards how they might be queried.

Let me try to explain a bit more. Say I have many cars moving around on a map and I want to determine if and when they're in a convoy. If I store just the paths then I can see that they travelled along the same road, but not if they were there at the same time. I can store the start and end times but that will not take into account the changes in speed of the two vehicles. I can't think of any obvious way to store and achieve this so I thought I'd put the question out there in case there's something I'm missing before trying to implement a solution. So does anyone know anything I don't?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what type of movement information you have.
If you have some tables setup like:

Vehicle (Id, Type, Capacity, ...)

MovementPoint(VehicleId, Latitude, Longitude, DateTime, AverageSpeed)

This would allow you to query if two cars going to the same point plus or minus 5 minutes like so:

```
Select * from Vehicle v INNER JOIN MovementPoint mp on mp.VehicleId = v.Id
WHERE v.Id = @FirstCarID 
AND EXISTS 
    (
     SELECT 1 FROM Vehicle v2 INNER JOIN MovementPoint mp2 on mp2.VehicleId = v2.Id
     WHERE v2.Id = @SecondCarId 
     AND mp2.Latitude = mp.Latitude AND mp2.Longitude = mp.Longitude
     AND mp2.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,-5,mp.DateTime) AND DATEADD(minute,5,mp.DateTime)
    )
```

You could also query for multiple points in common between multiple vehicles with specific time windows.

Also you could make the query check latitude and longitude values are within a certain radius of each other.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This is a lot like what I'm currently doing. I was just trying to discover if there was a smarter way of doing it by using the spatial data types in conjunction with some kind of time dimension. I understand that it's not currently supported but hoped that someone might have figured a workaround using perhaps a second geometry which has time and say distance as the axes. The ultimate gole is to have paths as units of processing rather than individual points. Using the start and end times is insufficient as the vehicles could be travelling opposite directions.